# Operating CORDIC IP VHDL

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I have been looking extensively into the operation of the CORDIC IP for use with Sin and Cos in VHDL.

According to page 24 of the CORDIC V6 documentation: https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/cordic/v6_0/pg105-cordic.pdf#G6.297366 , the Sin and Cos functionality with the module should only require a PHASE_IN to provide data, and should return an X_OUT and a Y_OUT corresponding to the sin and cos of the PHASE_IN respectively. The generated IP diagram also shows an aclk, s_axis_cartesian_tvalid and s_axis_phase_tvalid input are required, and the module returns s_axis_phase_tready, m_axis_dout_tdata, and m_axis_dout_tvalid. Table 2-1 indicates that PHASE_IN is on the input s_axis_phase_tdata, and X_OUT and Y_OUT are on the channel m_axis_dout_tdata. I have followed the steps on page 35 of the designing with IP guide: https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2019_1/ug896-vivado-ip.pdf  to generate an instantiation file which I have used to create a simple test bed.

However when I test a Sin Cos CORDIC IP while providing a constant aclk, setting the tvalid to high and proving a tdata of 0, I get nothing back from the module, even after waiting for a very large number of clock cycles (10000). I appear to get back undefined (U) values for both the s_axis_phase_tready and the m_axis_dout_tvalid along with a constant 0 from the m_axis_dout_tvalid, which seems to indicate something is wrong with my core instantiation, but I believe I have followed everything the documentation has provided.

I will promptly provide any new information if requested, but ultimately I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong to utilize this IP?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution to this problem, if anyone encounters this please check if this fix helps you.

The aclk seems to require an immediate delay before use, so ensure it stays at 0 for a whole clock cycle period before commencing cycles.

This is not mentioned in the text as far as I can tell, which made this issue very difficult to find.

Comment: Please explain in more detail, preferrably as a step-by-step description.